# How do I add a custom button next to the "Add Content" button?

Tags: 8

How can I add a button next to the *+ Add Content* button on /admin/content, in Drupal 8?

> [image: add content page]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to provide `mymodule.links.action.yml` in your module.

This is an example from core for the *Add content* action button from your question:

*node.links.action.yml*

```
node.add_page:
  route_name: node.add_page
  title: 'Add content'
  appears_on:
    - system.admin_content
```

Reference: [Providing module-defined actions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-actions)

Comment: Perfect! that works well, on a side note, do you know how to use that button to create form overlay for users to input data and then process that data?

Answer (score 1):

To further the answer above, if you want to theme the button you added from `MODULE.links.action.yml` you need to implement the following hook in you `MODULE.module` file:

```
function MODULE_menu_local_actions_alter(&$local_actions) {
  $local_actions['ROUTE.NAME']['options']['attributes'] = array(
    '#target' => '_blank'
  );
}
```

The above hook will add the attribute `target="_blank"` to the link